# Running scripts with dependencies in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am running scripts(bash/ansible) with relative path dependencies on other scripts from within a Jenkins pipeline. These scripts are scripts that are used for many projects so storing them directly in the source repository is not an option. Currently I am accessing these scripts and their dependencies by storing these scripts on the Jenkins master file system and calling them using the absolute file path.

Obviously, this is not very portable and I would like to do something like storing the scripts in a shared library and referencing them from there. Unfortunately, the *loadResource* command will only load a single resource and will not resolve any script dependencies which is of no value.

A couple of ideas I am considering:

- Put the scripts in a separate repository and download that repository into the build workspace and then access them from inside the workspace.
- Put the scripts in a shared library and then access them directly from the shared library download location(/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/foo-job)

Any thoughts on these ideas?
Is anyone using a different solution to reference a script with dependencies from within Jenkins?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the first option i.e. Put the scripts in a separate repo

Couple of reason

1. Shared library will still be referencing the location of the current unix system (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/foo-job), so if you do
   switch systems, then there is a chance of it failing. Defeats the
   whole purpose you were trying to achieve in the first place :)
2. You will have more control on your scripts and can be treated as a
   separate project if you want(creating it on a separate repo)

Another option is to tailor specify the scripts to that project, then you can add them directly to the existing projects.

Comment: Hi Rohit. Thanks for the response. These scripts are common to multiple jobs so storing them in the project repo is not practical. Putting them in a separate repo and pulling that repo into the workspace probably does make the most sense. That is actually what I am doing for running packer and terraform scripts but was hoping there was something in shared libraries I could leverage.

Comment: You might find [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) useful, though they have some drawbacks. A single repo for tools like this can be included as a submodule in several other repos, making it effectively a subdirectory that is separately managed in a repo of its own.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the suggestion. I did not realize git had the submodules feature, so that was good information. In some ways submodule would be the ideal solution, however, the common scripts I am using are used for about many, many repos, so updating all those repos with a submodule is not a practical solution. Appreciate the input.